# JSLigo Error: Invalid record field in record

Tags: ligo

I'm trying to write a smart contract with JSLigo. This contract has a storage type with a single string field and 2 functions, to update and reset this string:

```
type storage = {
    name:   string
};

type parameter =
| ["Update", string]
| ["Reset"];

type return_ = [list <operation>, storage];

let update = ([store, newValue] : [storage, string]) : storage => 
    ({...store, name: newValue});

let reset = ([store] : [storage]) : storage => 
    ({...store, name: ""});
    
    
let main = ([action, store] : [parameter, storage]) : return_ => {
 return [
   (list([]) as list <operation>),
   (match (action, {
    Update: (newValue: string) => update ([store, newValue]),
    Reset:     ()  => reset([store])}))
  ]
};
```

When I compile it (using https://ide.ligolang.org/), I get :

```
Error: File "/tmp/tmp-1WcZCXPyP3f4H.jsligo", line 15, characters 22-24:

Invalid record field "name" in record "store".
```

When I write my functions like this, it's OK:

```
let update = ([store, newValue] : [storage, string]) : storage => {
    let newStorage : storage = {
        name: newValue
    };

    return newStorage;
}
```

I don't understand what is my mistake with the record and the functional update. Do you see something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the `[store]:[storage]` which is accepted but not well managed by the compiler. An issue has been open for this purpose. Anyway if you want your code to compile remove the opening and closing square brackets as illustrated in the following code fragment:

```
type storage = {
    name: string
};

// ...

let reset = (store : storage) : storage => 
    ({...store, name: ""});
       
let main = ([action, store] : [parameter, storage]) : return_ => {
 return [
   (list([]) as list <operation>),
   (match (action, {
    Update: (newValue: string) => update ([store, newValue]),
    Reset:                 ()  => reset (store)
   }))
  ]
};
```

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the tip !